# Can Jenkins Pipeline Stash merge files?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm processing `integration` and `unit` tests in parallel. They both generate JUnit and Code Coverage reports under the `target` directory. The stash name for each of the them is `tests-build` and the resources included is also provided.

```
stage('Tests Execution') {
  parallel {
    stage('Execute Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        dockerExecuteBuildStage([ stageName: "unit-tests", dockerTargetDir: "/opt/build/target",
            stashIncludesPattern: "**/target/*", stashName: "tests-build"])
      }
    }

    stage('Execute Integration Tests') {
      when {
        expression { config.load().idpsIsEnabled == false }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          config.concurrentStash("tests-build", "intuit-paas-update.yml")
        }
        dockerExecuteBuildStage([ stageName: "integration-tests", dockerTargetDir: "/opt/build/target",
            stashIncludesPattern: "**/target/*", stashName: "tests-build"])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Considering they will be executed in parallel and will use `Jenkins Stash` to store the reports temporarily for a later processing, I'm getting the following behavior:

## Questions

- Can stash merge files while executing in parallel?
- is there a way to have the files from the 2 parallel stash to be merged? if the names don't collide?

## Behavior

- In a branch I got `Safe stashing paas-update.yml in faf7dfb5d4a66b14d5acdae4c46a8b8771b57beb-tests-build...`
- In the other branch I got `Warning: overwriting stash ‘faf7dfb5d4a66b14d5acdae4c46a8b8771b57beb-tests-build' Stashed 5 file(s)`

Comment: it can not merge. but you can use different names, and unstash to one dir -> merge -> do stash  again and then use only one stash